# Finding the eigenvalues of $A$ from $A^m = I$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a square matrix on $C$ such that $A^m = I$

We can conclude that $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ as $A^m = I \Rightarrow A^mv = Iv = v \Rightarrow \lambda = 1$

Now the answers conclude something that i dont understand:

They are basing there answer on the fact that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A \Rightarrow \lambda^m$ is an eigenvalue of $A^m$

Saying that therefore the eigenvalues of $A$ are of the form $cis(\frac{2 \pi k}{m})$

The question - I dont understand how they conclude that the eigenvalues of $A$ are of that form, of $cis(\frac{2 \pi k}{m})$ ?

Comment: What are the eigenvalues of $I$?

Comment: $cis(\frac{2\pi k}{m})$ are the $m$ roots of unity.

Comment: The eigenvalues of $I$ is 1

Comment: And this is equal to $\lambda^n$, so...

Answer (score 2):

No, $1$ might be an eigenvalue of $A$ but need not be.  For example,  $A$ might be $e^{2\pi i/m} I$ whose only eigenvalue is $e^{2\pi i/m}$.

$e^{2\pi i k/m}$ for integers $k = 0, 1, \ldots, m-1$ are the $m$'th roots of $1$, that is the solutions of $\lambda^m = 1$.  This is because 
$$ \left(e^{2\pi i k/m}\right)^m = e^{2\pi i k} = 1$$

Answer (score 2):

Your logic shows that $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A^m$, not of $A$ itself.

Their argument is: Suppose $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, so $Av = \lambda v$ for some vector $v$. Then 
$$A^m v = A(A(\cdots Av) = \lambda^m v,$$
so $\lambda^m$ is an eigenvalue for $A^m = I$. But the only eigenvalue for $I$ is $1$. Thus $\lambda^m = 1$, so $\lambda$ is an $m$-th root of unity, i.e. $\lambda = e^{2\pi i k/m}$ for some integer $k$.

Answer (score 1):

If $A^m=I$ and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with eigenvector $v$, then
$$ v=A^mv=\lambda^mv$$
and so $\lambda^m=1$ since $v\neq 0$. Hence the eigenvalues of $A$ are all $m$th roots of unity, and so are of the form $\exp(\frac{2\pi ik}{m})$ for some integer $k$.

Comment: Thanks but i feel that you just repeat what the answers say and i dont understand this

Comment: Which part is unclear?

Answer (score 1):

Ok i found it, i had a basic problem with complex numbers.

For future users that will be stuck like me i will write the answer:

If i have the equation:

$$
\lambda^m = 1 \Rightarrow |\lambda^m| = 1 \Rightarrow |\lambda|^m = 1 \Rightarrow |\lambda| = 1
$$

Therefore we get:

$$
\lambda = 1(\cos \theta + i\sin \theta) = \cos \theta + i\sin \theta 
$$

$$
\lambda^m = \cos m \theta + i \sin m \theta = 1
$$

Now, it is known that:

$$
1 = \cos 2\pi k + i \sin 2\pi k 
$$

Therefore:

$$
m\theta = 2 \pi k  \Rightarrow \theta = \frac{2 \pi k}{m}
$$

Therefore we get:

$$
\lambda = \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi k}{m}\right) + i \sin \left(\frac{2 \pi k}{m} \right) = \text{cis}(\frac{2 \pi k}{m})
$$